# if P=NP, why is P a subset of NPC?

Tags: complexity-theory, automata, np-complete

[image: venn diagram of P and NP]

Assuming P = NP, why should P be a subset of NPC?
Here is how I understand it:

1. P is a subset of NP
2. NPC is a subset of NP

if we solve an NP Complete problem on a deterministic machine in polynomial time then

3. NP is a subset of P
4. P=NP (from 1 and 3)
5. NPC is a subset of P (2 and 3)

But why is P a subset of NPC, if P = NP?
This question has been asked before and the answers just pointed to the definitions of NP, P and NP-C. I have gone through the definitions but still require a detailed picture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be in NPC a problem, C, has to be in NP, and every problem in NP has to be polynomial-time reducible to C.

If P=NP every problem in NP can be solved in polynomial time.

This means that if P=NP, we can for most problems in P define the following reduction to C; Solve the problem in polynomial time, if the instance you are looking at returns true then reduce it to an input to C for which we know that C returns true - Otherwise reduce it to an input for C that we know returns false.

So for an example; if we take C to the problem of determining if a number is even. And we want to reduce the hamiltonian path problem.  We solve the hamiltonian path problem; which we can do in polynomial time since we assume P=NP.  If we find that a hamiltonian path exists we select 2 as input to C.  If we find that no hamiltonian path exists then we select 1.

This of course fails if C always returns true, or always returns false, so those two problems, as noted by Tom, while part of P, can not be part of NPC.  However, all other problems in P will be in NPC if P=NP.

Comment: "all other problems in P will be in NPC if P=NP."

Does that mean: ((P = NP) implies (3-SAT is polynomially reducible to 2-SAT))? My understanding: 2-SAT is NL-complete; it is not known to be P-complete

Comment: @WordsLikeJared Yes.  You first run an polynomial algorithm to solve the 3-sat problem.  If P=NP then this is possible.  If the 3-Sat is satisfiable you reduce it to (x and x), if it is not satisfiable you reduce it to (x and not x).  This has little bearing on the P-completeness of 2-SAT.  See my example in the answer and note that determining if a number is even is certainly not P-complete.

Comment: Thank you! I understand your comment and answer, now.  Your original answer was clear.  I just didn't understand it, yet.  (This approach to reduction "feels like" "cheating" though)

Answer (score 7):

The premise of your question is false. If $P=NP$, then the middle drawing ("This is true...") is wrong and the third ("but why not this?") drawing is correct.

> Assuming P = NP, why should P be a subset of NPC?

$P$ is not a subset of $NPC$, and this is unconditionally true.

There are two very trivial problems in $P$ that can never be $NP$-complete: the empty problem (where the answer is always "no"), and $\Sigma^*$ (the problem consisting of the set of all inputs, where the answer is always "yes"). These problems are not $NP$-complete because a reduction (showing $NP$-completeness) must map yes-instances to yes-instances and no-instances to no-instances, but if there do not exist any no- or yes-instances to begin with this is impossible.

Comment: It should be noted that those are the **only** problems in P not in NPC. OP probably got their second drawing from places like wikipedia which opt for a simple drawing with an added text disclaimer like "(excluding the empty language and its complement, which belong to P but are not NP-complete)"